# how to completely uninstall everything from ubuntu 14.10

Tags: uninstall

I am kind of new using ubuntu and i wondering is there was a code that i can run that will completely remove everything installed and return it to a state similar to when i finished installing the OS itself

Comment: You could enlight us and mention at least what software/packages did you install? Please edit your question.

Comment: @xangua It wouldn't really matter what he installed, he's looking for a generic command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to restart from scratch, I would follow **Patrick's advice** and just reinstall the OS.

However, if you want to reset the way your desktop originally looked, then follow the instructions below.

I you want to reset your unity desktop and compiz, open your terminal and type

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

then type

```
setsid unity
```

If you want to reset the unity default icons, type

```
unity --reset-icons
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be doing such a wipe as that, just backing up and reinstalling the OS is the easiest way. You could go into the Software Centre and look at what is installed, there, and uninstall based on History or *what you have installed.* There isn't a script for everything! ;D

Comment: You could make one though, by looking at all dependencies for ubuntu-desktop and purging any package that is not necessary for an Ubuntu Desktop system.